# Debugging mBed-OS 5 using J-Link OpenSDA Firmware and GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, mbed, segger-jlink

I am working with a [MK64FN1M0xxx12](https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/FRDM-K64F/) development kit that supports OpenSDA. To make things easier to debug, I flashed the [J-Link](https://www.segger.com/opensda.html) firmware that supports the SEGGER debugger command set. Before doing this I made sure my device was [officially supported](https://www.segger.com/jlink_supported_devices.html).

To be more verbose, I am trying trying to debug [mbed-os 5](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os), specically the [uVisor](https://github.com/ARMmbed/uvisor) security patches. The uVisor Github page has a [debugging write-up](https://github.com/ARMmbed/uvisor/blob/master/docs/api/DEBUGGING.md#enabling-runtime-messages) that provides instructions for connecting to the device over a GDB session to receive debug prints. I was able to get the J-Link session properly connected, but I cannot seem to actually debug the binary. Further, I cannot seem to properly flash the device. I am able to push the binary to device RAM, though.

Their instructions read:

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:2331
(gdb) monitor reset
(gdb) monitor halt
(gdb) monitor semihosting enable
(gdb) monitor loadbin ./build/${target}/source/${your_app}.bin 0
(gdb) monitor flash device = ${device_name}
(gdb) load ./build/${target}/source/${your_app}
(gdb) file ./build/${target}/source/${your_app}
```

So, I tried to replicate their work. Connect to the device over J-Link

```
$ JLinkGDBServer -device MK64FN1M0xxx12
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.00g Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.00g (DLL compiled Aug 17 2016 13:20:32)

-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 MK64FN1M0xxx12
Target interface:              JTAG
Target interface speed:        1000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link OpenSDA 2 compiled Sep 15 2016 14:57:31
Hardware: V1.00
S/N: 621000000
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.30 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...ERROR: Debugger tries to select target interface JTAG.
This interface is not supported by the connected emulator.
Selection will be ignored by the DLL.

J-Link found 1 JTAG device, Total IRLen = 4
JTAG ID: 0x2BA01477 (Cortex-M4)
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...
```

Establish GDB client session

```
(gdb) target remote localhost:2331
Remote debugging using localhost:2331
0x200171fe in ?? ()
(gdb) monitor reset
Resetting target
(gdb) monitor halt
(gdb) monitor semihosting enable
Semi-hosting enabled (Handle on BKPT)
(gdb) monitor flash download 1
Flash download enabled
(gdb) shell cp ../.build/K64F/GCC_ARM/mbed-os-example-uvisor.bin /tmp
(gdb) monitor loadbin /tmp/mbed-os-example-uvisor.bin
Binary file loaded successfully (210240 bytes downloaded)
(gdb) monitor flash device = MK64FN1M0xxx12
Selecting device: MK64FN1M0xxx12
(gdb) load ../.build/K64F/GCC_ARM/source/main.o
Loading section .text._ZN4rtos6ThreadC2E10osPrioritymPh, size 0x54 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN16NetworkInterfaceD2Ev, size 0x28 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN16NetworkInterfaceD0Ev, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed10DigitalOutC2E7PinName, size 0x24 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed10DigitalOut5writeEi, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed10DigitalOutaSEi, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata._ZL10g_main_acl, size 0xc0 lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata.__uvisor_priv_sys_irq_hooks, size 0xc lma 0x0
Loading section .keep.uvisor.bss.boxes, size 0x80 lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata.__uvisor_mode, size 0x4 lma 0x0
Loading section .keep.uvisor.cfgtbl, size 0x28 lma 0x0
Loading section .keep.uvisor.cfgtbl_ptr_first, size 0x4 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._Z30local_ENET_Transmit_IRQHandlerv, size 0x14 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._Z29local_ENET_Receive_IRQHandlerv, size 0x14 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN16NetworkInterfaceC2Ev, size 0x18 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN12EthInterfaceC2Ev, size 0x24 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN12EthInterfaceD2Ev, size 0x30 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN12EthInterfaceD0Ev, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN17EthernetInterfaceC2Ev, size 0x24 lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata, size 0xd4 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._Z16ethernet_connectv, size 0x54 lma 0x0
Loading section .text.main, size 0x174 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed8CallbackIFvvEEC2EPS1_, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed8CallbackIFvvEE6attachEPS1_, size 0x30 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN4mbed8CallbackIFvvEE12_staticthunkEPvS3_, size 0x14 lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata._ZTV12EthInterface, size 0x24 lma 0x0
Loading section .rodata._ZTV16NetworkInterface, size 0x18 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN17EthernetInterfaceD2Ev, size 0x30 lma 0x0
Loading section .text._ZN17EthernetInterfaceD0Ev, size 0x1c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, size 0x3c lma 0x0
Loading section .text._GLOBAL__sub_I___uvisor_priv_sys_irq_hooks, size 0x10 lma 0x0
Loading section .init_array, size 0x4 lma 0x0
Start address 0x0, load size 1816
Transfer rate: 1773 KB/sec, 56 bytes/write.
(gdb) file ../.build/K64F/GCC_ARM/source/main.o
A program is being debugged already.
Are you sure you want to change the file? (y or n) y
Reading symbols from ../.build/K64F/GCC_ARM/source/main.o...done.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
rtos::Thread::Thread (this=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffff4>, priority=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffff2>, stack_size=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffec>, 
    stack_pointer=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffe8>) at ../mbed-os/rtos/rtos/Thread.h:42
42          Thread(osPriority priority=osPriorityNormal,
(gdb)
```

Resulting J-Link console output

```
Waiting for GDB connection...Connected to 127.0.0.1
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x200171FE (Data = 0xEA126221)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x200171FE (Data = 0x6221)
Resetting target
Halting target CPU...
...Target halted (PC = 0x200171FE)
Semi-hosting enabled (Handle on BKPT)
Flash download enabled
Loading binary file [/tmp/mbed-os-example-uvisor.bin] ...
Downloading 210240 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Binary file loaded successfully (210240 bytes downloaded)
Selecting device: MK64FN1M0xxx12
Downloading 84 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 40 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 36 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 192 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 12 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 128 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 40 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 20 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 20 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 24 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 36 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 48 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 36 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 212 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 84 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 372 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 48 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 20 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 36 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 24 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 48 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 28 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 60 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 16 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Writing register (PC = 0x00000000)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x00000000)
Read 2 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x0000)
Reading all registers
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x00000000)
Starting target CPU...
ERROR: Can not read register 15 (R15) while CPU is running
Reading all registers
ERROR: Can not read register 0 (R0) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 1 (R1) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 2 (R2) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 3 (R3) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 4 (R4) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 5 (R5) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 6 (R6) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 7 (R7) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 8 (R8) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 9 (R9) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 10 (R10) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 11 (R11) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 12 (R12) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 13 (R13) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 14 (R14) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 15 (R15) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 16 (XPSR) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 17 (MSP) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 18 (PSP) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 24 (PRIMASK) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 25 (BASEPRI) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 26 (FAULTMASK) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 27 (CONTROL) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 32 (FPSCR) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 33 (FPS0) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 34 (FPS1) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 35 (FPS2) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 36 (FPS3) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 37 (FPS4) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 38 (FPS5) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 39 (FPS6) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 40 (FPS7) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 41 (FPS8) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 42 (FPS9) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 43 (FPS10) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 44 (FPS11) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 45 (FPS12) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 46 (FPS13) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 47 (FPS14) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 48 (FPS15) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 49 (FPS16) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 50 (FPS17) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 51 (FPS18) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 52 (FPS19) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 53 (FPS20) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 54 (FPS21) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 55 (FPS22) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 56 (FPS23) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 57 (FPS24) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 58 (FPS25) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 59 (FPS26) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 60 (FPS27) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 61 (FPS28) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 62 (FPS29) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 63 (FPS30) while CPU is running
ERROR: Can not read register 64 (FPS31) while CPU is running
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x00000000)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x00000000)
Read 4 bytes @ address 0x00000000 (Data = 0x00000000)
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFF4
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFF2
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFEC
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0xFFFFFFE8
```

It seems things are *almost* working, but I am not well enough versed in GDB to know where things may be failing. From the J-Link console output it appears as if the second `load` is overwriting the early contents of RAM. If I omit this instruction (but keep the last `file` command) then then no errors will be reported, but the connection via `nc` does not display any debug messages

```
$ nc localhost 2333
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.00g - Terminal output channel
```

Despite the uVisor debug write-up (following the GDB command list) indicating that many types of messages should be reporting at run-time. In addition to this, my program that was (seemingly) successfully downloaded to the board does not behave as it should when executing (no blinking LEDs, etc).

As I have found a few times before with uVisor (since it is *very* new), the documentation may be out of date. Also, I found through my research that others required the use of the `monitor flash download = 1` command to enable flash programming, although it did not seem to work for me. Although the output of this command reads `Flash download enabled`, nothing is ever written to flash as far as I can tell (considering the output and elapsed time).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to properly attach and receive debug statements using the following command set:

```
file ./build/${target}/source/${your_app}.elf
target remote localhost:2331
monitor reset
monitor semihosting enable
load
```

It seems it is necessary to load from debug symbols from the elf and not delegate loading the binary via the `monitor` command proxy. Further, it appears the `load` command considers the last file to be to used as its default target (the *.elf, in this case). This seems strange, however, considering that mBed-OS does not parse ELF headers or *load* anything ...

At any rate, the output in the J-Link console looks much more like I expected:

```
Downloading 1024 bytes @ address 0x00000000
Downloading 16 bytes @ address 0x00000400
Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00000410
Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00001410
Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00002410
Downloading 4096 bytes @ address 0x00003410
...
```

This is not a complete solution so I will not mark it as such.